# Do while loop repeats in C

Tags: c, input, newline, scanf

**PROBLEM** I type `y` as an option and it prints the text twice before prompting me again when it's supposed to only print it once.

**CORRECT OUTPUT** (what im supposed to get but not getting):

```
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? y
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)

Do you order FISH (Y/N)? y
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)

Do you order FISH (Y/N)? n

Do you order CHIPS (Y/N)? n

Do you order DRINKS (Y/N)? y
Drinks choice (S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea)

Do you order DRINKS (Y/N)? n
```

**WRONG OUTPUT** (the output I get)

```
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? y
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? y
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut)
Do you order FISH (Y/N)? n
Do you order CHIPS (Y/N)? Chips choice (C- Cut, R- Ring)
Do you order CHIPS (Y/N)? n
Do you order DRINKS (Y/N)? Drinks choice (S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea):
Do you order DRINKS (Y/N)? n
```

**RAW SOURCE** (in case you want to compile it yourself and check whats up): http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mZ1jVrF0

**SOURCE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char fishYesNo, chipsYesNo, drinksYesNo;
    char *typeOfFood;

    do {
        typeOfFood = "fish";
        printf("Do you order FISH (Y/N)? ");
        scanf("%c", &fishYesNo);
        if (fishYesNo != 'n') {
            printf("Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut) \n");

        }
        else if (fishYesNo == 'n') {
            typeOfFood = "chips";
        }

    } while ((strcmp(typeOfFood, "fish")) == 0);

    do {
    typeOfFood = "chips";
        printf("Do you order CHIPS (Y/N)? ");
        scanf("%c", &chipsYesNo);
        if (chipsYesNo != 'n') {
            printf("Chips choice (C- Cut, R- Ring) \n");
        }
        else if (chipsYesNo == 'n') {
            typeOfFood = "drinks";
        }

    } while ((strcmp(typeOfFood, "chips")) == 0);

    do {
    typeOfFood = "drinks";
        printf("Do you order DRINKS (Y/N)? ");
        scanf("%c", &drinksYesNo);
        if (drinksYesNo != 'n') {
            printf("Drinks choice (S- Softdrink, C- Coffee, T- Tea):\n");
        }
        else if (drinksYesNo == 'n') {
            typeOfFood = "fish";
        }

    } while ((strcmp(typeOfFood, "drinks")) == 0);

}
```

Comment: You're scanning a single character, but you have to press enter after entering the character, so there's a new-line character after the Y or N.  You end up reading that the second time around.

Comment: Fixed it with `" %c"` instead of `"%c"`. Thanks. How can I mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: I've seen this a million times but I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: I've only seen it twice, but that's enough for me to not duplicate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a well-known conceptual error in C. The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/index.html) (which I suggest you read) has a lot of information on this and other gotchas.

Explanation of what's happening in your code ([comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 12.18b](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html)):

> You wanted `scanf %c` to read a single character, and it tried to, but
>   when you tried to type that single character at it, before the rest of
>   the input system would accept it, you had to hit the `RETURN` key, too.
>   `scanf` read only the one character, but that extra newline was still
>   sitting in an input buffer somewhere, and it's that extra newline
>   (seemingly representing a phantom blank line) which was received by
>   your later input call.

How to deal with it, from a review of `scanf`'s problems ([comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 12.20](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)):

> It's nearly impossible to deal gracefully with all of these potential
>   problems when using `scanf`; it's far easier to read entire lines (with
>   `fgets` or the like), then interpret them, either using `sscanf` or some
>   other techniques.

Comment: More reviews of the problems with `scanf` can be found by entering `site:stackoverflow.com scanf chris lutz` into Google. ;)